# pass input value to onclick function

Tags: javascript

Can anyone give me a "trick" how to pass input value to  "a" element onclick function.

Let say i have input field with specific id:

```
<input id="yourname" type="text" value="Testing Value" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your name here..." >
```

and function "exportText" which actualy export text (html) from specific div id (biography):

```
<a   href="#" onclick="exportText('biography', 'Name of player');">

                Save your biography
            </a>
```

When you click a href link it will save biography in txt document with name: "Name of player.txt"

How can i force the function to actually grab the input id "yourname" value and save the  .txt document with that name, something like    "yourname+.txt"

I really tried to search a solution over the net, but my knowledge is too low to found an answer on myself.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have to create one JavaScript function in that you can get the value of input yourname. After that, you can proceed for creating the file.

Comment: Maybe i didnt say, i already have working function to export file its called "exportText". The function itself has variable/parameter  // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.txt':'yourname.txt';  Does this piece of code help?

Comment: Still not clear what you want to say. It would be nice if you share the whole code

Comment: Can i share you a fiddle link to look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your exportText function, if it's a ***local*** function you can directly use

```
document.getElementById('yourname').value;
```

instead of 'Name of player' parameter
Now, if it's a global function, you can play with a specific class (Ex:ClsUserName) and in your exportText use

```
document.getelementsbyclassname('ClsUserName')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event:

```
input id="yourname" value="Testing Value" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your name here..." /> 
<a href="#" id="exportText">Save your biography</a>
```

and js:

```
document.getElementById('exportText').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('yourname').value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the tag.

Due to the button being inside the form, it will submit the form to the server and reload the page. As the form is submitted, and page load happened you will not be able to see the text assigned to the div.

Comment: Not sure which question you are answering, but it does not seem to be this one.